# Android facebook Login Widget: org.json.JSONException

Tags: android, xml, json, facebook

I am trying to learn and use Facebook SDK in my project, 
First I was getting:
com.facebook.widget.loginbutton failed to instantiate

then I started getting:

activity_main.xml: org.json.JSONException
and whenever I launched app I got:

```
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:372)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:667)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:1)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-05 23:45:44.180: E/AndroidRuntime(31957):    ... 4 more
```

I am following Facebook SDK documentation on facebook developers and just completed step 1, the app is 100% exactly same written as facebook documentation explains.

The JSON error is thrown when I open xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and press Graphical Layout.

Any help please? been stuck with this for past 12 hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

changes your application manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.MainActivity" >


 </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"   android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Remember to go to your App's [Dashboard](http://developers.facebook.com) page on the Facebook developers website and copy your application id, then create the string resource in `res/strings.xml` file

`<string name="app_id">YOUR APP ID</string>`

Comment: @BadrEddine Its still not working for me, the login widget is throwing exception in xml itself

Comment: Please note that hardcoding the app id will also not work. It is needed to create strings resource.

Comment: Adding the metadata fixed it for me. One difference was that I had to add com.facebook.FacebookActivity not com.facebook.LoginActivity

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.
After made the download of Facebook's SDK 3.14 in https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip and update SDK in my project, the same error occurred.
I tried to clean the project many times and build it again without success.

So I've read the article "Getting Started" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) again and I found this information:

"You must unselect the 'Copy projects into workspace' option so that each of the sample projects retains a correct reference to the neighboring SDK. However, this means that Eclipse creates a link to the project in the SDK installation, rather than making a copy of it."

Therefore, try to remove Facebook SDK and examples of your workspace, if you have imported, and import it again with "Copy projects into wordspace" unselect.
Refers the Facebook's SDK and restart Eclipse again.

Thats works for me.