# Facebook login NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Am trying to implement the Facebook login for Android using the Facebook SDK (3.17.1) but i am having some issues i haven't had in the past.
First of all, the login button doesn't render completely. This is what i get

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

(notice the missing Facebook logo). When I run the application, in the split second before it crashes it displays it just the way it should (with the Facebook logo).

When the application crashes, i get this error message

`"Unfortunately, FacebookLoginTest as stopped"`

and this in Logcat:

```
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731): Process: com.example.facebooklogintest,    PID: 7731
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error   occured while executing doInBackground()
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at     android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:911)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at   com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:377)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:677)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton$1.doInBackground(LoginButton.java:1)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-12 22:19:08.751: E/AndroidRuntime(7731):     ... 4 more
08-12 22:19:10.753: D/Process(7731): killProcess, pid=7731
08-12 22:19:10.753: D/Process(7731):   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:131    java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

I followed the instructions for adding Facebook login to Android apps:

1. Imported Facebook sdk
2. Added Facebook project as libray
3. Added Facebook project to list of references for my project
4. Cleaned and even restarted the project.

Besides these, I haven't changed anything in my Activity and manifest.
I have tried this in three different eclipse versions, all with the same error, but then i delete the Facebook login button code in the .xml file, the app lauches just fine. 
Not sure what else am supposed to do.
Here are the MainActivity and Layout.xml codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.facebooklogintest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.facebooklogintest.MainActivity" >



<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your ASynctask that deals with the loggin in to facebook please. It's failing within an ASync task

Comment: Like i said, I haven't added any login functionality.I just added the button and was just trying to test the display on my device.This isn't supposed to be a problem.

Comment: Can you post your activitys xml and code please

Comment: I just added those to the question.

Comment: Did you delete your answer?

Comment: Someone deleted it. I'll add it again shortly when I'm on my pc

Comment: Okay.Because I followed the instructions in the link you provided and it worked for me.

Comment: Added my answer again, please mark as accepted and please mark up to the guy who answered it in the post i linked. Thanks

Comment: Done that already.Thanks. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to change or add this in your manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.MainActivity" >


 </activity>
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"   android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

I cannot take credit for this, all credit must go to the guy who posted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483262/android-facebook-login-widget-org-json-jsonexception) I am purely adding the code for ease for you and because I got told to by someone who previously deleted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915): Process: com.example.version_2, PID: 25915
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:822)
10-10 11:27:47.932: E/AndroidRuntime(25915):    at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:489)
```

If you face above error in FB integration then the below solution will work. Just add Application ID in Meta-data tag in menifest file. It will work fine

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Comment: This question was asked a year ago.  It is unlikely that the person asking the question is still having issues, but you can provide your answer in the hopes that it helps others.  In that case, however, you should take extra care to present the answer with proper formatting, and ensure that your answer is extremely clear.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will take care.

Comment: perhaps you misunderstand.... This question was flagged because of it's content.  You should correct this answer.

Comment: To clarify the  `<meta-data android:value` needs to be a String resource i.e 
`@string/facebook_app_id"` not the actual value.

Comment: @scottyab - Thanks a lot!